# Generate the Unique 18 to 25 size random nummber in multiple application servers

Tags: java, spring, performance, web-applications, application-server

I am using the 5 application servers and 10 web servers.

Presently i am generating the Unique random number based on YYYYMMDDHHMMSMILLI(year month day hours mints seconds milli seconds) but some times application servers get the request's at same time(YYYYMMDDHHMMSMILLI) this case i am getting the duplicate random number.

I check possible ways like storing the number into Database but not useful because multiple application servers generating the number at same time.

Please help me to possible ways to generate unique random number.

Answer (score 2):

If your random ID does not need to be related directly to a timestamp (i.e. does not need to imply chronological order) you should use a [Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Variants_and_versions) (random) [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), generated by

```
UUID.randomUUID()
```

UUIDs have 128 bits and the chance of a duplication is infinitesimal.

If you need to preserve chronological order then append a server identifier to your current generation strategy.

Comment: Correct answer. UUIDs were invented to solve *exactly* the problem described in this Question.